# How to check if there are no matching elements in two lists of objects?

Tags: c#, list, iteration, match, intersect

I have two lists of objects: `List<One>` & `List<Two>` and I want to achieve the following.

For each `One.Id`:

- if there's a matching Id in `Two.Id`, do nothing
- else if there are no matching Ids in `Two.Id`, do something

I tried with iteration inside iteration, but couldn't find a suitable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's Any() method to check for presence of matching items:

```
foreach (var one in listOne) {
    if (!listTwo.Any(two => two.Id == one.Id)) {
        // No matches
    }
}
```

Comment: Working. Thank you.

Comment: I took adjan's answer, removed the method as I didn't need it and used the foreach, but doing so it's the same as your answer, so both are good for me. Can I accept both?

Comment: @Tomo Answers to simpler questions tend to be similar. SO does not allow accepting multiple answers. It does not matter which one you accept: the idea behind it is to let other site visitors know that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Any()` in a dedicated function like this:

```
bool HasMatches(List<One> ones, List<Two> twos)
{
    foreach (var item in ones) {
        if (!twos.Any(other => other.Id == item.Id)) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You should finish the search once you have found no match for the current item.

Comment: Working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like this

```
List<one> a = new List<one>;
List<two> b = new List<two>;

foreach( l in a)
{
    if(b.Any(x=>x.id == l.id)){
    //do something
    }
    else{
    //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var item1 in list1)
{
    if(list2.Any(item2=>item2.Id== item1.Id))
    {
        //do nothing
        continue;
    }
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` like this.

```
bool isContainId = List<one>.Contains(two.Id);

if (isContainsId)
{
     // do something
}

else
{
     // do something
}
```